# Adding init and reset methods to my singleton

Tags: ios, singleton

My singleton looks as follows:

header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject
{

    MyManager *_sharedObject;


}


@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString * nameTitle;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString * nameDescription;



//assets
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * assets;


+ (id)sharedInstance;

@end
```

implementation

```
#import "MyManager.h"

@implementation MyManager

@synthesize listingTitle;
@synthesize listingDescription;


//Assets
@synthesize assets;

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}
@end
```

I would like to know add 2 more methods that would allow me to initialize and reset properties at any time. I was thinking to use the init method for the initializing and also add another method that would reset . Would this be the correct approach?

Something like this:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

         [self reset];

    }

    return self;
}

-(void)reset {

self.listingTitle=@"";
self.listingDescription=@"";

}
```

would this be the correct way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you must have seen here, there is no absolute correct way to do anything. But I have done this in other apps and I believe it will work well for you. In fact, when you do subclasses that can be instantiated in a nib (with initWithCoder:) and also in a normal way (initWithFrame:), this technique also works well. The idea is to NOT duplicate code but put the it on one place and call it from multiple places.

If you were to instantiate mutable objects, you'd want this to be two stage - add the mutable objects in 'commonInit', then have that call 'reset' to insure everything is as you want a pristine object to be in.

Answer (score 1):

Naming a method `init` that's not intended to operate on a freshly-allocated instance strikes me as wrong. But a `reset` method that restores your object's properties to sensible defaults seems fine to me.